# Como resolver ioexception em arquivo xls gerado por jett?

Tags: jsf, relatório, jee, apache-poi

Pessoal tenho um bean com metodo de gerar relatorio assim feito com jett:

```
Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    beans.put("fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo", fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo);
    try {
         ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer();
         transformer.transform("template.xls", "precificacao.xls", beans);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException reading " + "template.xls" + ": " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("InvalidFormatException reading " + "template.xls" + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

estou tendo uma IOException justamente no transformer.transfom(...) , sendo que coloquei template.xls na mesma pasta do bean; na verdade fiz igual a documentação do jett e eles não explicam muita coisa la. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi passando a entrada como InputStream não String:

```
Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();

beans.put("fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo", fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo);

try {

    InputStream inPath = ProdutoManagedBean.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.xls");

    ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer();
    transformer.transform(inPath, beans);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A documentação do jett não fala nada a respeito isso, acho até um pouco pobre.